# Best way to handle calling the US from overseas?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an app for a radio program which includes a number of phone numbers, all US. I have gotten feedback from an international user who mentioned that "+1" needed to be added to the numbers for the numbers to work internationally. What's the best way to handle this?

Can I just add +1 to all of the numbers? Or will this cause odd charges for domestic callers?

If so, do I need to put a preference in, or is there some *reliable* localization or geographic info I can pull to automatically add the +1 when needed?

Comment: I hope you put a "you know, you're calling the U.S. and this might be expensive" alert up before allowing the user to proceed....

Comment: Yes, there is an alert that pops up before the call is initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with international phone numbers you have to work with what it is called the E164 format which describes the international format of a phone number for every country. Before I go into details I would like to say that if you are inside a country (say USA in this example), then it does not matter if you add the +1 or not as the carrier will add it automatically when the call is placed. But when you go world wide you need to be in E164 format to be on the safe side.

Personally I needed such a thing in one of my apps and I did a personal function that takes a phone number as a string and the country code (also as a string) and returns the E164 format for that number.

Why I did this function? Because as you know on one's device you might see numbers stored in different layouts like:

- (02) 1234 5678
- 02 1234 5678
- 0411 123 123
- 1 300 123 123
- 1300 123 123
- 02-1234-5678
- 1300-234-234
- +44 78 1234 1234
- +44-78-1234-1234
- 0011 44 78 1234 1234
- (44) 078 1234 1234

And you need to handle them before you can use them. My function doesn't take into consideration numbers of this format: +44-(0)78-1234-1234 but you can add it if you need it.

Here is my function:

```
- (NSString *) phoneToE164:(NSString *)originalString CountryCode:(NSString *)countryCode
{
    //strip the string from symbols
    NSString *strippedString = [[originalString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSMutableString *finalString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:strippedString];

    //if the first character is + your done
    if( [originalString characterAtIndex:0] == '+' )
    {
        [finalString insertString:@"+" atIndex:0];
    }

    //if the first 2 characters are 00 replace them by +
    else if( ([finalString characterAtIndex:0] == '0') && ([finalString characterAtIndex:1] == '0') )
    {
        [finalString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
        [finalString insertString:@"+" atIndex:0];
    }

    //if the first character is 0 replace it with country code
    else if( [finalString characterAtIndex:0] == '0' )
    {
        [finalString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        [finalString insertString:countryCode atIndex:0];
    }

    //anything else is unknown format, just insert the country code
    else if( [finalString characterAtIndex:0] != '0' )
    {
        [finalString insertString:countryCode atIndex:0];
    }

    //return the result
    return(finalString);
}
```

By the way, this function can work for any country not only USA, simply send it the country code you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, `+1` should not cause a problem - I live in the UK and have all my numbers prefixed with `+44` to avoid any possible problems.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it will not cause any extra charges.** Even people in the United States can put +1 at the beginning of their phone numbers and it will not make a difference.